# 64 bit eclipse rcp product doesn't run in 64 bit OS + 32 bit compiled & bundled JDK 1.7 32 bit kit

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I am facing problem with running Eclipse RCP product. I have made 64 bit eclipse rcp product in 32 bit jdk but  it doesn't run in 64 bit OS + 32 bit compiled & bundled JDK 1.7 32 bit kit. While exporting product actually i checked "Bundle JRE for this environment with the product" from "Launching" tab from .product file because I am using JCE policies which i need to over right on existing JRE and hence I use to export with bundle JRE.

Once my product is generated in 32 & 64 bit version, 32 bit product works file but when i open 64 bit product it says "Failed to load the JNI shared library '..\win32.win32.x86_64\eclipse\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll' ". I replaceed jre with original JRE which is in my installed directory but again failed and same above message comes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 64 bit Eclipse **must** be run using a 64 bit JRE. You cannot mix 64 bit and 32 bit Eclipse / Java.

Comment: Yes. That way it works. But I am using "Bundle JRE for this environment with the product" while creating product where I have 32 bit bundled JRE. So which one I should bundle for 32 & 64 bit product ?

Comment: You will have to build two products. One completely 32 bit and the other completely 64 bit.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks Greg !